# Android, Migrating Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase generates: "This project uses AndroidX dependencies"

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, androidx

**I'm working on a company project that is already in the store for years, using Fabric. When trying to migrate to Firebase, it forces me to use AndroidX, but as the code is old this generates hundreds of errors and becomes unviable. Does anyone have an idea on how to use Firebase Crashlytics WITHOUT using AndroidX? Or does anyone know another way to avoid this error?**

Comment: You have to move to AndroidX.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thnks, I will try it but theres too much changes that i have to do so.

Comment: Note that Support Library 28.0.0 is *exactly identical* to AndroidX 1.0 in everything but package names. You should always get a no behavior difference migration if you move between exactly those versions.

Comment: Firebase Crashlytics SDK is now deprecated and will no longer report your app's crashes starting November 15, 2020. 

Details here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android